# Grid format HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a section on my html where I can show some grids. Can you help me with this please? I'm attaching a pic where I'm showing what I want to do. Yellow color is how it is right now, and blue is the final result.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.a {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.b {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.c {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.d {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The blue box doesn't have anything. Are you trying to position the grid?

Comment: @RameshReddy that's right, I'm trying to position the grid and text in the blue area. Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on your HTML. You could create the blue layout and nest `.wrapper` inside it. If the positioning is relative to another element, you can use `position: relative` and `position: absolute`.

Comment: Could you put up more complete HTML. We don't know what the structure of the Projects text is so any answer given will be just a guess.

Comment: Thank you @RameshReddy for the advice, much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you  @AHaworth I was able to create the grid, it seems that the position was affecting the layout. Best regards.